# odoo v14: importing tickets and its messages from xlsx or eml

Tags: import, odoo

I'm using odoo v14.

I have been trying to make a .xlsx file that can import both tickets and messages that are related to the tickets. I'm trying to relate them via message.res_id but i'm getting error (i'm translating from spanish so maybe the error message is not precise):

```
Unknown error during import <class 'KeyError'>: 217 between rows 2 and 4
```

Is it actually possible to import tickets and its messages? Or if I can import the from .eml directly the better.

My last resort will be to load them directly to the tables.